# Python: accessing previous elements in list "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple"

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm trying to write a Python program to go through two lists `x[ ]` and `y[ ]`. The elements in the lists are read from a file. Each `x[ ]` element has a corresponding `y[ ]` element. `x[ ]` and `y[ ]` are plotted against each other on a graph (were plotted, but plotting removed because not necessary for this code).

I want to integrate the graph over `x[ ]` and to create another list `cumulative[ ]`. I'm trying to get the n'th element of `cumulative[ ]` to hold the value of the integral between the 1st `x[ ]` element and the n'th `x[ ]` element.

Before appending `cumulative[ ]`, I try to declare variables that refer to the i'th `x[ ]`, `y[ ]` elements and to the i-1'th elements. This is where the following error message appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/andy_experiments/cumulate1", line 39, in <module>
    xprevious = x[i - 1]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int' "
```

I've looked at other people's working Python codes to access previous/next values in lists, and I can't figure out why my code fails to do that.

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []
cumulative = []

readFile = open('data_03.txt', 'r')
sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')

readFile.close()

count = 0

# The code was originally used to plot data, hence "plotPair" (line in the file)
for plotPair in sepFile:
    if plotPair.startswith("!"):
        continue
    if plotPair.startswith(" !"):
        continue
    if plotPair.startswith("READ"):
        continue
    if plotPair.startswith("NO"):
        continue
    if plotPair == "\n":
        continue
    if not plotPair.strip():
        continue
    else:
        xAndY = plotPair.split('    ')
        x.append(float(xAndY[0]))
        y.append(float(xAndY[3]))

for i in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
    count = count + 1
    if count < 2:
        continue
    else:
        xprevious = x[i - 1] # this is line 41, where the (first) error lies
        xnow = [i]
        yprevious = y[i - 1]
        ynow = y[i]
        cumulative.append((xnow - xprevious)*(ynow - yprevious))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enumerate()` yields a sequence of tuples; the index and the element from the wrapped iterable. You are trying to use that tuple; for a `zip(x, y)` sequence that means you get a sequence with `(0, (x[0], y[0]))`, then `(1, (x[1], y[1]))`, etc.

Unpack the tuple into the index and the `x, y` pair:

```
for i, (xval, yval) in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
    if i > 0:
        xprevious = x[i - 1]
        yprevious = y[i - 1]
        cumulative.append((xval - xprevious) * (yval - yprevious))
```

I replaced the `count < 2` test with a test for `i` as well.

You could more easily track the previous pair simply by assignment:

```
previous = None
for xval, yval in zip(x, y):
    if previous:
        xprevious, yprevious = previous
        cumulative.append((xval - xprevious) * (yval - yprevious))
    previous = xval, yval
```

Comment: @martineau ah, misread the handling of `count`; it is incremented, *then* tested.

Comment: IMHO, the first version is easier to understand and could be shortened further to just: `xprevious, yprevious = x[i - 1], y[i - 1]`.

Comment: Seems like you could get rid of the `if` statement in the loop altogether with something like `xprevious, yprevious = x[0], y[0]`, then `for i, (xval, yval) in enumerate(zip(x, y)[1:], start=1):`, `»...`.

Comment: @martineau: sure, but the `previous = current_loop_data` approach works for iterators too, so you could use `itertools.izip()` here now and not worry about memory usage.

Comment: True, a classic speed vs memory trade-off I suppose...`zip()` and `izip()` really ought to have an optional `start=` keyword argument to tell it to skip that many initial entries of all iterables passed.

Comment: @martineau: that is what `itertools.islice()` is for though.

Comment: Sort of, but it would need to be applied to each argument iterable separately.

Comment: @martineau: does it matter if it is applied to the inputs or just the output? For `izip()` not really.

Comment: True, the end result would be the same, however, for this specific case, a simple `for i, (xval, yval) in enumerate(izip(x[1:], y[1:]), start=1):` would be both memory efficient and faster I think (and therefore suffice).

Answer (score 1):

You need to unpack the tuples returned by `enumerate` which will be `(index, value)`. For example:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> y = [2,4,6,8]

for index, pair in enumerate(zip(x,y)):
    print(index)

0
1
2
3
```

Your current indexing is using these tuples as indexes, which is what the error is telling you

```
for i in enumerate(zip(x,y)):
    print(i)

(0, (1, 2))
(1, (2, 4))
(2, (3, 6))
(3, (4, 8))
```

The quickest change you can make to fix your code is to change your `for` loop to

```
for i, pair in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
```